# How to fix app theme

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing a new version of already developed app. Right now i am facing this weird problem that no matter background color i set in xml but when app runs it show dark colored background, kinda blackish.

Here is the styles.xml. Note colorPrimary,colorPrimaryDark,colorAccent are of green color.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <!--<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>-->
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <!--<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>-->
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
        <!--<item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>item-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Here is how it looks. Basically this is a dialogue box inside a activity.
[image]

Here is how it should apear instead of above image. Screenshot of android studio xml preview
[image]

Please help me out!

Edit

Here is xml of activity and fragment

Activity's xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/consumer_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Fragment's xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.test.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here java code of dialogue.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.consumer_welcome_dialogue);
            dialog.show();
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Here is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.SplashSecond"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.ConsumerRetailerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:label=" "/>
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.consumer.TestLoginConsumerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:label=" "/>
    <activity
    android:name=".updated.activities.consumer.TestSignUpConsumerActivity"
    android:label=" "
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.retailer.TestRetailerSignUp"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.retailer.TestRetailerLoginActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.retailer.TestRetailerAccountActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.consumer.TestTabConsumerActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label=" "
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CatagActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.consumer.ConsumerHome"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.consumer.ConsumerSignUp"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.retailer.RetailerSignUp"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.retailer.RetailerHomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.retailer.MyStoresActicity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.retailer.AddStoreActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".activities.retailer.StoreBranches"
        android:label=" "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.retailer.AddBranchActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SettingActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.consumer.MySubscriptionsActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.consumer.AddSubscription"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.consumer.SubscribeBranchesActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".activities.retailer.RetailerPromotionsActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.retailer.RetailerHomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.wisaver.app.activities.retailer.RetailerHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.consumer.Consumer_Offers"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.consumer.ConsmOffersActivity"
        android:label=" "
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.OfferDetails"
        android:label=" " />
</application>
```

Here is xml preview of with background pic. I simply added `backgroud="drawable/backgound"`
It should appear in app like this but it doesn't show background it stead it shows black colored background

[image]

Comment: Please show the XML layout of your activity or fragment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ok wait editing the question in a while

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Wow, didn't see anyone who uses `Developers Tools`...

I think that your problem is a problem with your `Dialog`.
Did you tried to use the dialog constructor with the `Theme` ?, like this : `new AlertDialog/*.Builder*/(Context context, int theme);`

Comment: First. I do follow developers tool. Second this isn't AlertDialogue issue. This is related to theme actually. Whole app has backgroud as black and there is no where that color resouce is mentioned inside the app. I have double checked it

Comment: Could you add the Java code you use to show the dialog ?

Comment: You can apply the constructor I suggested for a `Dialog`, like this : `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyTheme); // if it's the right theme`

Comment: That wouldn't change the backgroud of activity. Why the app theme isn't working here?

Comment: Could you add your `Manifest.xml` ?

Comment: ok. Here is another thing. I have added background images in xml but in app it doesn't show those xml also instead a black color shows up.

Comment: What is the name of your main activity (the one on the pictures) ?

Comment: You said you had background pics, can you add or modify question code to show how you did it ?

Comment: added more detailds to the question

Comment: You forgot `@` before `drawable`, no ?

Comment: Could you try adding `setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);` before `setContentView()` in your Java code activity ?

Comment: Maybe you use an AppCompat Theme, which isn't a light theme, but maybe a dark theme.